# Split value by int to multiple row MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to split the value by using mysql method

```
Example
ID|| Item name || Quantity
1 ||   ABC     ||    3
2 ||   DEF     ||    3

SELECT * from table

End up result wan to be like this 
1 ||   ABC     ||    3
1 ||   ABC     ||    3
1 ||   ABC     ||    3
2 ||   DEF     ||    3
2 ||   DEF     ||    3
2 ||   DEF     ||    3
```

will loop all the result by quantity

Comment: You need a numbers table to do this

Comment: Can provide some example of the number table mean ?

Comment: Just google *mysql numbers table*

Comment: What u mean is create a number table and using looping to insert each line ? after that using join function go get the value ?

Comment: Create an in-line numbers table, then join your table to it to get repetition

Comment: Got Other way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a numbers table. There are a lot of ways to produce one, you can find them on stackoverflow. For this purpose here I'll just create a small one with `UNION`, but it may be a good idea to create a permanent one.

```
SELECT
Id, ItemName, Quantity
FROM
your_table
JOIN (SELECT 1 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) numbers 
ON numbers.n BETWEEN 1 AND your_table.Quantity;
```